# Manipulate the Laravel default login authentication

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Is there a way I could manipulate the login authentication of Laravel 5.2, I want to change it like, use 'username' instead of 'email' and change the return response as a JSON response?

In Laravel 5.0, I can do it like.

In routes,

```
//authentication routes
Route::controllers([
    'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
    'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
]);
```

In AuthController,

```
public function postLogin(Request $request)
{     
    $this->validate($request, [
        'username' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);

    $credentials = ($request->only('username', 'password'));
    if ($this->auth->attempt($credentials)) :   
        return response()->JSON([ 'success' => true, 'message' => 'Successfully logged in, redirecting...' ]);
    else:
        return response()->JSON([ 'success' => false, 'message' => 'Invalid username or password!' ]);
    endif;

}
```

any help, ideas, clues, suggestions, recommendations please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel 5.2 comes with some functionality in the AuthenticatesUsers trait (See vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php). All you need to do is add the following to your AuthController.

```
// Change the field we grab the username/email from
public function loginUsername()
{
    return 'username';
}

// If the login is successful, send this as the response
protected function handleUserWasAuthenticated(Request $request, $throttles)
{
    return response()->JSON([ 'success' => true, 'message' => 'Successfully logged in, redirecting...' ]);
}

// If the login fails, return this as the response
protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    return response()->JSON([ 'success' => false, 'message' => 'Invalid username or password!' ]);
}
```

All the functions are outlined in AuthenticatesUsers.php. Hope this helps!

Edit: As stated below, you will need to add the request facade to your controller:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

Comment: I have this error after added your answer to the authController.php

"Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController::sendFailedLoginResponse() must be an instance of App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Request, instance of Illuminate\Http\Request given, called in C:\wamp\www\Clinic and Inventory System\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers.php on line 85 and defined"

Comment: Hi, sorry about that - Just add the request class at the top of your controller-use Illuminate\Http\Request;

If there are any further errors, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to change the credentials array:

```
$credentials = array(
    'email'                => Input::get('email'),
    'password'             => Input::get('password')
);
```

and in your case:

```
public function postLogin(Request $request)
{     
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email'    => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);

    $credentials = ($request->only('email', 'password'));
    if ($this->auth->attempt($credentials)) :   
        return response()->JSON([ 'success' => true, 'message' => 'Successfully logged in, redirecting...' ]);
    else:
        return response()->JSON([ 'success' => false, 'message' => 'Invalid username or password!' ]);
    endif;

}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: where I can find that credentials array and that 'public function postLogin'?

Comment: whhaaat ?? I've copied your code!! What are you asking?? I don't understand